# Why do some variants miss the subscription-related fields like requires_selling_plan?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template, shopify-api

According to [Shopify variant liquid object](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/variant#variant-requires_selling_plan), there are subscription-related fields like requires_selling_plan, selling_plan_allocations, etc.

But I can't find these fields on my variants. I tried to add subscription plans to my products with Recharge or Awtomatic subscription apps. But these fields are still not found. How can I add these fields to my variants? And why are they missing? I can't find any information from the subscription docs.

Answer (score 1):

After researching for a day, I found out that the payment gateway is the cause. When I was using Bogus gateway, these fields were not shown. After that, I switch to Shopify payment with test mode on, these fields appear.

I guess it's related to the [Eligibility requirements](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/products/subscriptions/setup?shpxid=4671a154-E527-4EED-EFE4-A9FF13663A35#eligibility-requirements)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a subscription to a variant or not. You can therefore expect to find a mix of selling plan information per variant. It is up to you to check for the presence or absence of selling plans per variant.

Comment: I found out the reason already. It's due to the payment gateway. Thanks for your feedback